# Jmeter: How to fix java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, distributed

I am doing distributed testing using `Jmeter`. 
I have just added some libraries for performance monitoring in JMeter lib folder, But i am not using them in test plan. I am using JMeter 2.11
Its working fine when I run all the slave using GUI mode, but when i run `Jmeter` in `Non-Gui mode` for distributed testing following error comes:

```
:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\JMETER\MyTest\PROJECTS\VTWebsite\VTWebsiteLoadTest.jmx  -R 192.168.16.20,192.168.16.60,192.168.16.36,
192.168.16.43 -l C:\JMETER\MyTest\scriptresults.xml
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=64m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using C:\JMETER\MyTest\PROJECTS\VTWebsite\VTWebsiteLoadTest.jmx
Configuring remote engine for 192.168.16.20
Using remote object: UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.16.20:52964](remote),objID:[56a2dc3:14834aeb7c8:-7fff, -626516943481154007]]]
Configuring remote engine for 192.168.16.60
Using remote object: UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.16.60:30000](remote),objID:[ab46ff4:14834bcd76c:-7fff, 5068970606656314471]]]
Configuring remote engine for 192.168.16.36
Using remote object: UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.16.36:40419](remote),objID:[340a5477:14834aaa2a2:-7fff, -1824599565201262756]]]
Configuring remote engine for 192.168.16.43
Using remote object: UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.16.43:16035](remote),objID:[5e920c9d:14834ec4eac:-7fff, 3726006617068851172]]]
Starting remote engines
Starting the test @ Tue Sep 02 11:50:51 IST 2014 (1409638851668)
Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jmeter.engine.JMeterEngineException: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling argume
nts; nested exception is:
        java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using JDK8 which is not supported yet.

Version 2.12 will support Java 8.

I suggest you install last version of Java 7 and try again.

Comment: I have just added some libraries for performance monitoring in JMeter lib folder, But i am not using them in test plan. I am using JMeter 2.11

Comment: I am using Jmeter 2.13 and I was still having the same exception when running remotely from command line. I had to install JRE 1.7. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error when another (but same) instance of JMeter was running on Master. Termination of this "old" instance solved the problem.